# dotnet publish results include different set of libraries when run in linux/windows

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface

While configuring some of our gitlab runners - some Windows, others Linux - I noticed something I find curious. The artifacts created by Linux runners include some libraries that are not included in the artifacts created by Windows runners.
The files in question are:

- System.Collections.Immutable.dll
- System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
- System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll

This happens no matter if a target runtime has been specified or not, e.g.

```
dotnet publish ./Project/Project.csproj -c Release
```

will include the three files mentioned above when run under Linux, but not when run under Windows (SDK 3.1.300). The project runs just fine without these.

Can anyone explain what's happening here? I was under the impression the result of a dotnet publish command is always the same regardless of the OS.

Comment: Do you also see this behaviour with a "HelloWorld" project?

Comment: Good suggestion. When creating a new console project, those files will be included in the deployment (after referencing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, as I found out), no matter the OS. So, apparently I should be asking why those files are missing when I run dotnet publish of our project on windows.